# Why are notifications about replies to comments on deleted questions sent, if the person whose comment is being replied to has <10k rep?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-questions, notifications

On this question ([Copy constructor using scope resolution operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69602230)) I've got [a reply](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/123025440?noredirect=1) to one of my comments.

However, as I have <10K rep, I won't be able to view the reply to the comment (apart from the part that appears in the notification bar).

Is there a special reason for these notifications to be sent, or is this just a little something that skipped the scrutiny tests?

---

Probably not needed, but a screenshot of the actual question: (Umm... no, don't get me wrong, this is Google's cache)

[image: thank you dear google :)]

Comment: I imagine the reason is simple: 1. You get a reply. 2. The system sends a notification. 3. The post is deleted. End. This leaves the notification already sent. I don't think there is a specific code that says "if the post is deleted and there is a reply to the comment, then send the reply".

Comment: @VLAZ, can't we change that to *4. Delete the reply notification*? It shouldn't be too hard; just like when you delete the reply itself and the notification gets deleted, similarly, when the question gets deleted, the notification should too (although selectively, i.e. for users with <10K rep). Speaking of rep, why such a restriction in the first place?

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him As far as I can remember, the notification _is_ cleared after the post is deleted. Are you sure the notification remains in your inbox even after refreshing the page?

Comment: @41686d6564 It's still there!

Comment: [It's not working! Should I blame caching?](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: @yivi, I have restarted my machine since then, and it still is showing up! Also, I have disabled the caching in my browser long back

Comment: There are more caching layers between heaven and earth than are dreamt by your browser of choice (hint: server side caching).

Comment: @yivi Normally, that notification is cleared right away. I don't think this is a caching issue. Of course, it _could_ be, but then most likely, there would be a bug somewhere that caused it to be cached that long.

Comment: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html

Comment: There's already an easy solution to this issue. Just get your rep up to 10K, and you'll be able to read the entire comment from the deleted post. :-)

Comment: There's a `Responses` tab in your Profile that you can check to see if the response notification is still there. If you haven't looked at that previously, then cacheing shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: My guess is that the notification is there to enable moderator comments on deleted posts to notify low-rep askers. Normally these comments are aimed at the author, who can see their deleted question. I assume it would be added complexity for little practical benefit to add a filtering step of "will the recipient actually be able to see the post?". You can always try opening a feature request for this.